# Different sorting by name in Windows Explorer and other Apps

Tags: windows-explorer, 7-zip, sorting, rename, naming

i noticed Windows Explorer and many apps like Winrar sort folders by name like this order:

(test

)test

.test

@test

_test

+test

0test

1test

atest

-atest

but in some other apps like 7z and unlocker, i noticed that behavior is different:

(test

)test

+test

-test

.test

0test

1test

@test

atest

_test

i wanna pin my important folders to top with renaming them by some special characters (like + _ . ) but after this experience, im little confused. can i fix sort order in 7z and similar apps?
i dont wanna use numbers in first letter because i used numbers for remembering my works and tweaks and etc order so reusing numbers for my main folders confuses me even more. if this annoying sort order will be fixed, i can use + and . and _ for my main folders.
otherwise, folders with _ will show the latest items in 7z and some other programs, as well as folders with + and . are reversed.

thanks

Comment: Windows does not sort the way you want. Consider just arranging manually.

Comment: Yes, I sort everything by name manually, but as I said, sorting by name behaves differently in some apps. Do you confirm it? Also, if you mean by manually to disable auto-arrange in Explorer, it's impossible in Windows 10.

Comment: If you wish to auto arrange, you need to accept the order Windows / Explorer does it.

Comment: i think you didnt read my main post carefully. the Explorer isnt my problem. other apps with strange sorting are the problem. also this sorting appears in many installers when you browse the installation folder.

Comment: I did read your post, but most apps sort the same way Windows does. I do not see any way to pin your particular order of items to the top with the provided sort orders.

Comment: An app developer sorts their list view any way they please.  The listview control has it's own sort routines but they only specify off, ascending, or descending.  This default sucks when it comes to sorting numbers and other things.  Apps like the windows explorer (and many others) provide their own code to do the sort.  You can't control what a developer did in their code without hackery beyond most people's skills.